# Emulate video source in GTV device (Revue)?

Tags: google-tv

School is having a science fair where we will present a Google TV app, but the problem is that there are no cable lines to connect to, and GTV emulators can't communicate with Anymote protocol(Which we need to multiscreen).

Our only way was to at least emulate a channel lineup into the real device(Revue), but is there a way to do it? I heard the channel list is acheived from the ContentsProvider, can one push the Emulated Channel List into the real device? We don't need to show a show or some thing, we just need to get the channel list and change it like the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify the scope of this answer:

- This will NOT play any content, the "TV-Signal" will be a blank screen.
- All this does is to properly populate the channel line up content providers so that an application will see a "valid" set of channels.
- As a side-benefit - This will also show a current list of shows and movies in the "TV&Movies" application for demo purposes. Of course when you select to play a channel, the rule above applies, and you will see a black screen.

With those expectations... here's how you do it:

- Go to **System Settings**
- Select **Video Input**
- Chose **Add device manually**

At this point you see a window which reads "You should see your TV signal playing above". Naturally, since you don/t have a settop box connected, this will be a black window.
When asked to confirm that you see your TV signal playing, chose **Next**

- On the next screen you select the radio box for option **"Cable box, Satellite Receiver"** then chose **Next**
- The next screen gives you a list of satellite and cable providers in your area (depending on your ZIP code, make sure you set a valid ZIP code before, or change in Settings->location)
- Select an available provider - my favourite in my area is "Dish Networks". They have a lot of options.
- Depending on the provider, the next screen may let you chose a "basic" or "full" integration. Given this choice, chose **"basic"**.  (Full integration will actually require a 2-way communication with the settop box!)
- On the next screen titled *"IR Blaster Setup"* you configure a fake settop box. Chose for example the following options:

  - Device Type: Cable/IPTV
  - Manufacturer: General Instruments
  - Model: DCT1000
  - Command Set: C0476   (or whatever is offered in the choices)
- Next up you see a screen where you can test the "channel up/down",  ignore and just say **"Next"**

Finish the setup - congratulations, you have now configured a "fake" Set-top Box with your Google TV.

The Channel Lineup content provider will return the channel information for the provider you have chosen.
Note: The choices of available services and line-ups may vary geographicaly. If the choices above are not available for you, use other locally available service providers.
The only real key is to select a "basic" integration, since then the Google TV device does not receive any feedback from the settop box, and has no way of knowing if it is actually connected to a "real" settop box.

*Bonus Feature*:  If you demo this, you may simply connect the HDMI input to a DVD player or any other device (e.g. a Laptop HDMI out). This way you can at least have *some* video playing for demos even if the channel change does not have any effect. I use this setup frequently when demonstrating Google TV in locations without "live" video signal.